# How can I make sure I don't run out of meat?

Tags: rimworld

In the current version of Rimworld (Alpha 10f), is there any way I can make sure my colony never runs out of meat for meals? I know that I can switch over to nutrient paste or simple meals, but I'd prefer to have at least fine meals. I also know that I can buy enmass from other tribes or the bulk cargo ship, but that is not reliable and is a major hassle.

Specifically, I'd like to create a large, self sustaining colony, but the limiting factor seems to be meat. It is something that requires constant attention and seems to be a rather limited (or at least slowly replenishing) resource. Realistically it seems rather difficult and tedious to sustain a population of more than 5-6

Comment: Don not underestimate the power of veggies!

Comment: If you're not into cannibalism... at the moment I don't believe it's possible to self-sustain a stock of meat. "Animal pastures" would potentially (if they ever exist) be a method of doing this, but they are not in the game (maybe a mod?). You can do things to slow down meat consumption, such as forbidding the Nutrient paste dispenser from using it, but the only methods of acquiring more to my knowledge are manual hunting/trading. **But!** If you're into cannibalism, allow butchering the dead from the frequent raiding parties! That should provide a steady income of meat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Core, there's currently no reliable way to resolve this.

There are [auto hunt mods](https://ludeon.com/forums/index.php?topic=8930.0) which partially address this.

I'm playing with a large modset, so I have tried that particular mod on it's own, but the gist is that any animal that strays near a beacon will be marked for hunting.

That helps, but doesn't, for example, cover you if winter drives all animals away.

I've also seen "meat substitute"-mods, which makes it easier to provide fine meals.

Answer (score 2):

In vA15 one can make fine meals using milk.  So a herd of muffalo can keep you going.